# Wireshark: Unable to compile a plugin

Tags: plugins, makefile, compilation, wireshark

I have been trying to compile a small plugin in wireshark (1.5.0) on Fedora 14. There is a single C file call pv.c

I created a directory under plugins and copied my C file. Then I took the Makefile.am and Makefile.common from plugins/interlink directory and modified to change plugin name, version and SRC directories. I also copied moduleinfo.h into my plugin directory.

Here are changes I made to Makefile.common:

```
PLUGIN_NAME = pv
DISSECTOR_SRC = \
 pv.c
```

Here are changes I made to Makefile.am:

```
plugin_LTLIBRARIES = pv.la
```

I also adapted $(wireshark)/plugins/Makefile.am/common to include my pv directory under plugins to be compiled. I did the same for root Makefile.am and Makefile.common

But after doing all of this, after ./configure when I make the build; I keep on getting this error "No rule to make target 'all'. Stop". I assumed that make process will automatically generate the plugin.c, makefile.in and makefile in my plugin directory and then the process will continue.

Could any one point out that where I am missing the link here?

Best Regards
Omer

Answer (score 2):

Hi
 I think I am too late for the reply, but, just in case you haven't got the answer...

The problem is that you are not changing the configure.in file in the wireshark root directory.Just try adding th path to your plugin in this file . Somewhere near the line 1861.
Let me know if still you have problem..

Regards
Ankith